# using tsql to create a contigious time line set

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Long time reader, first time poster. Hoping some SQL guru can lend me some processing power to solve a SQL problem elegantly and without cursors.

I am trying to create a time line type result set from a data set with money and a Date, where the order in which they appear is important. See sample data and expectation below.

```
DECLARE @OrderData TABLE(
      ID                      INT IDENTITY,
      ProductId               INT,
      WarehouseId             INT,
      Cost MONEY,
      SaleDate          DATETIME
)
```

```
INSERT INTO @OrderData
VALUES
      (1, 1, 2.71, '2012-02-23 10:01')
      ,(1, 2, 2.71, '2012-02-23 10:02')
      ,(1, 1, 2.71, '2012-02-23 10:03')
      ,(1, 1, 2.71, '2012-02-23 10:04')
      ,(1, 1, 2.71, '2012-02-23 10:05')
      ,(1, 1, 2.8, '2012-02-23 10:06')
      ,(1, 1, 2.9, '2012-02-23 10:07')
      ,(1, 1, 2.71, '2012-02-23 10:08')
      ,(1, 1, 2.71, '2012-02-23 10:09')
```

The result I am looking for is a time line of sales with from and to dates for a product and warehouse combination within it own set of sales. As soon as the sale price changes in the dataset  this should spawn a new row in the result set.

Result structure for sample data.

```
Product, warehouse, minsale date, Max sale date
1,1,2.71, 2012-02-23 10.01, 2012-02-23 10.05
1,1,2.80, 2012-02-23 10.06, 2012-02-23 10.06
1,1,2.90, 2012-02-23 10.07, 2012-02-23 10.07
1,1,2.71, 2012-02-23 10.08, 2012-02-23 10.09
1,2,2.71, 2012-02-23 10.02, 2012-02-23 10.02
```

Cheers for any help available.

Comment: Can you explain the last row of your sample result please? Why isn't it already dealt with by the first row?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Did you mean the only `warehouse=2` one?

Comment: @AndriyM - yes, my eyes somehow glossed over the 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "gaps and islands" problem.

```
select ProductID, WarehouseId, cost, MIN(saledate), MAX(saledate) from
(      
    select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by saledate)-
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cost order by saledate) grp
    from @OrderData
) v
group by ProductID, WarehouseId, grp, cost
order by WarehouseID, MIN(SaleDate)
```

For further information, search for "gaps and islands by itzik ben-gan"

Comment: Probably you forgot to include `product` and `warehouse` into partitioning (in both ROW_NUMBERs).

Comment: @AndriyM I wasn't sure from the sample data whether they should be included or not, so i left them out for clarity of how the result set is calculated

Comment: Actually I think I overthought that, sorry. The additional partitioning is not needed, as `grp` wouldn't be used in grouping without both `ProductID` and `WarehouseID` anyway. I guess I was having a fit of hyper-correction there or something. I've got absolutely no problem with this answer now.

Comment: Thanks @podiluska, what an easy solution. Awesome. :)